# How to return DataSet (xsd) in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd

I have a library that returns a DataSet on a certain method. I need to expose this DataSet over WCF, the client app will use this as a datasource for a report generator (DevExpress XtraReport to be exact). The DataSet contains about 58 DataTables, including a table containing configurations for the report.

How can I get this dataset over wcf to the client (ASP.NET MVC)

current code

```
public ReponseData GetReportData (RequestData request){
 var reportData = library.GetReportData(request.Param1, reqest.Param2)   //returns DataSet

   var respone = new ResponseData {
        RequiredField = value, //requied for validation on the client
      //When I put DataSet here my wcf just breaks entirely 
      //.. what to do here to send over the DataSet??
   };
return response;

}
```

Comment: What is ResponseData? Is the code above you WCF web method? You just need to have a return type of DataSet in your service.

Comment: why not use xml/json instead(and in fact DataSet might be transferred as xml)

Comment: @Wheels73 I get an error on the client: "The underlying connection was closed unexpectedly". but nothing is wrong (or throws any exceptions on the WCF).

Comment: How long does it wait before this happens. Datasets are notoriously slow due to the amount of serialization that has to occur between service and client. If you have 58 datatables, you may want to try splitting this up into smaller requests.

Comment: Oh alright.. lemme get to it

Comment: splitting isn't possible, I don't own the code for the library (was developed by a senior dev ..). I opted for the below answer which seemed to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is use the DataSet’s methods to get the data in XML format and pass the XML string instead of the DataSet itself to the service.

```
PassDataSet(dsDataSet.GetXmlSchema(), dsDataSet.GetXml())
```

Comment: Thanks !!.. I ended up sending out the xml string instead of the DataSet