# How pass dataset to WCF method as a parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, dataset

In there i used this code to read data of excel file and it's work for me properly. But i need to save this dataset to database with `WCF`. So think pass the `dataset` to wcf method to achieve this.But how can i do this

this is i tried  code with windows form application

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       OpenFileDialog opn = new OpenFileDialog();
       opn.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

        if (opn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;

            FileStream strm = new FileStream(opn.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            IExcelDataReader excldr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(strm);

            DataSet rslt = excldr.AsDataSet();

           // while (excldr.Read())
           // {
           //    Console.WriteLine(excldr.GetString(1));
           // }
  }
```

I need to pass `DataSet rslt` to `WCF` method and within `WCF` i think to write save data function.is this good practice or not ? So how i can i do this

Comment: please take a look at this post: [How to return DataSet (xsd) in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087380/how-to-return-dataset-xsd-in-wcf/43088142#43088142)

Comment: Ok thank you :) i'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment I thought I should give you some example how to tackle this problem in a *slightly* better way.

My approach would be to initialise Request/Response `DataContract` objects that allows client to send the dataset and receive the acknowledgement more effectively.

Here is the `DataContract` classes:

The request object that client will instantiate and populate and send to the service:

```
[DataContract]
public class SaveDataSetRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public DataSet Data { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

   // you can add more properties here in the future versions without effecting the existing clients.
}
```

The response object that service will instantiate and populate and send back to the client:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class SaveDataSetResponse
 {
    public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

The service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    SaveDataSetResponse SaveDataSet(SaveDataSetRequest request);
}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public SaveDataSetResponse SaveDataSet(SaveDataSetRequest request)
    {
        SaveDataSetResponse response = new SaveDataSetResponse();
        try
        {
           // save or processes your data set from request.Data object,
            // once this operation is completed successfully then return the success message.
            response.Message = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log your exception 
            response.Message = $"Unable to save / process the data. Reason: {ex.Message}";
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

You will need to update the service config something like this (if you havent)

```
<endpoint
      address="http://localhost:8000/<namespace>/IDataService"
      binding="netTcpBinding"
      contract="<namespace>.IDataService"
      name="DataService">
</endpoint>
```

On the client, update the service reference (adding a new version of service dll or service url - WSDL), create an instance of client proxy class and call `SaveDataSetResponse SaveDataSet(SaveDataSetRequest request)` method. Make sure that the client config - endpoint is also updated with new contract if you are copying this code as is.

Some useful links:

- I would recommend [the following book](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9781430233688?wt_mc=PPC.Google%20AdWords.3.EPR436.GoogleShopping_Product_UK&gclid=CjwKEAjw2qzHBRChloWxgoXDpyASJAB01Io0suQP-UAkdKB66wm0wrZCuMojjw5fhheDMhGXuCJyFBoC2i7w_wcB) on WCF if you are new or
  need a refresh:
- If you have plural sight access then [this course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wcf-fundamentals) would be a good
  starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much :D your answer is really helped to me :) i'll do so

Comment: @SachithMW - Should you need further assistance let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a DataTable or a DataSet through WCF is a highly debated topic.
It can be done easily, however Personally i prefer to pass the data itself and not the metadata (columns and rows definitions, data relations etc.)
I usually declare an object , expose it to WCF and transfer it.

For each of the tables in your DataSet You can do something like the following  (not tested) :

```
 public class ExcelService : IExcelService
{
    public List<CustomExcelData> GetExcelData()
    {
        List<CustomExcelData> excelDataList = new List<CustomExcelData>();
        OpenFileDialog opn = new OpenFileDialog();
        opn.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

        if (opn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return null;

        FileStream strm = new FileStream(opn.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        IExcelDataReader excldr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(strm);

        DataSet rslt = excldr.AsDataSet();

        DataTable dt = rslt.Tables[0];

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelDataList.Add(new CustomExcelData(row));
            }
        }

        return excelDataList;
    }
}
```

and the interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IExcelService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<CustomExcelData> GetExcelData();
}

[DataContract]
public class CustomExcelData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public CustomExcelData(DataRow row)
    {
        Name = row["NameField"].ToString();
        Address = row["AddressField"].ToString();
        BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(row["BirthDateField"].ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem :)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service2Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service2Client();
    OpenFileDialog opn = new OpenFileDialog();
    opn.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

    if (opn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;

    try
    {
        FileStream strm = new FileStream(opn.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        IExcelDataReader excldr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(strm);
        DataSet rslt = excldr.AsDataSet();
        obj.insertExecl(rslt);

    }
    catch (IOException x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
    }
}
```

**Service2.cs**

```
public class Service2 : IService2
{
    public void insertExecl(DataSet rslt)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        foreach (DataTable table in rslt.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                tblExcel addTbl = new tblExcel()
                {
                    SID = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
                    Name = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                    Address = Convert.ToString(dr[2])
                };
                conn.tblExcels.InsertOnSubmit(addTbl);
            }
        }


        conn.SubmitChanges();

        //excldr.Close();
        //strm.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("successfully");

    }
}
```

**IService2.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    void insertExecl(DataSet rslt);
}
```

Comment: Your code is good for a school assignment but definitely not acceptable for a production level application. I would recommend the use of 'DataContract' and 'DataMemeber' pattern for transferring objects to / from WCF Service. What if your requirements change and you also need to pass other related information like file name? You will then change the signature of the method that will have knock-on effect on the clients. Just solving a problem is one thing, using best practice is quite another. I would encourage you to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza I'm novice for a WCF and i really don't know these things what u said. thank u very much for the comment :) and please tell me what is the best way to do this instead of my answer.please provide me an answer